# How to execute the jenkins job automatically once in a day

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In the jenkins' job, we have an option "Build Periodically". So what will be the parameter to run the job automatically at 10:30 pm IST time .

I tried 30 22 * * TZ=IST as a parameter but it's not working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on the question-mark right beside the schedule box to get a thorough explanation of the syntax.
It says there:

```
This field follows the syntax of cron (with minor differences). Specifically, each line consists of 5 fields separated by TAB or whitespace:

MINUTE HOUR DOM MONTH DOW

MINUTE  Minutes within the hour (0–59)
HOUR    The hour of the day (0–23)
DOM The day of the month (1–31)
MONTH   The month (1–12)
DOW The day of the week (0–7) where 0 and 7 are Sunday.
```

So in your case you need to put:

```
30 22 * * *
```

Concerning timezones the docu says:

```
Time zone specification

Periodic tasks are normally executed at the scheduled time in the time zone of 
the Jenkins master JVM (currently Europe/Berlin). This behavior can optionally 
be changed by specifying an alternative time zone in the first line of the field. 
Timezone specification starts with TZ=, followed by the ID of a time zone.
```

Thus your complete cron entry is:

```
TZ=Asia/Istanbul
30 22 * * *
```